# Jstree default to all nodes?

Tags: jstree

Jstree default to all nodes? I have two types of trees, has been loaded one of them will not be given, once again to load another will be given an error. Hope to give me a solution。

[image: enter image description]

Comment: Please show the code where you call `this.get_node()` method

Comment: .on("open_node.jstree",a.proxy(function(a,b){this.get_node(b.node,!0).find(".jstree-clicked").parent().children(".jstree-wholerow").addClass("jstree-wholerow-clicked")},this)).on("hover_node.jstree dehover_node.jstree"